# Problem of linking an Observable to a component

Tags: angular, observable

First of all, excuse my English, I'm using a translator.

I have a problem linking an observable that I believe in a service to a one-component variable. Here is the code:

servicio1.ts

```
         private myObservable$ = new Subject<myInterface>();
            constructor() { 
              this.crearObservable$();
            }

         nuevoObjeto(dato1: string, dato2: string): myInterface {
              return {
              datoUno: dato1,
              datoDos: dato2,
             };
         }
    
         crearObservable$() {
              let observableAUX: myInterface;
              observableAUX = this.nuevoUsuario("Dato 1", "Dato 2");
              this.myObservable$.next(observableAUX);
         }

         getObservable$(): Observable<myInterface> {
              return this.myObservable$.asObservable();
         }
```

componente1.ts

```
         datos: Observable<myInterface>;
         datos: Usuario;

         ngOnInit(): void {
            this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
            this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
            console.log(this.datos);
         }
```

Of course both the service and the interface are imported nowhere.

But for some reason this.data doesn't get the values.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try and log inside the subscribe. Observables are not synchronous.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Questions must be in English if you feel better asking in spanish you can use the spanish stackoverflow https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @Gecko Thats not true. Observables CAN be async. https://christianlydemann.com/are-observables-async/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had to subscribe before broadcasting, so I only had to call createObservable$() after I subscribed:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
    this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
    console.log(this.datos);
    this.servicio1.crearObservable$();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the information you're getting, you might have an asynchronous problem. Two things to be aware:

1. It's ok to save a snapshot of the Observable value like this, but if you care about accessing right after the value, it might not work because you once you `subscribe` you are waiting for the Observable to emit, and that can happen after you try to use the snapshot (in your example the this.datos variable)
2. If you want to access the value inside of the Observable, access it inside the subscribe callback function, like this:

```js
      ngOnInit(): void {
            this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
            this.datos$.subscribe(datos => {
                this.datos = datos
                console.log(this.datos)
            });
         }
```

EDIT: Looks like the problem might be the Observable itself. You are returning the Observable with `asObservable()`, which creates a new Observable as shown [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject#asobservable-).

Try returning the Observable as it is (it's okay to return Subject without asObservable, as subject is a special type of Observable after all)

Comment: Even if you try to view the this.data variable later with a one-button event, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you check to see you're actually getting the value? You can check using tap:

this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$().pipe(tap(console.log));

Comment: To test, I manually enter the values in service1.ts by making observableAUX = this.newUser("Data 1", "Data 2");

Comment: does not receive anything